# Unless and grep not work correctly

Tags: perl

Why in perl not work next code?

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $list=[{"name"=>1},{"name"=>1},{"name"=>2}];

foreach my $cat(@{$list}) {
    unless(grep { $_->{name} eq 3 } @{$list}+0) {
        print $count;
    }
}
```

print not return any result, but if i declare variable count, condition **unless** magic way start work

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $list=[{"name"=>1},{"name"=>1},{"name"=>2}];

foreach my $cat(@{$list}) {
    my $count=grep { $_->{name} eq 3 } @{$list};
    unless($count) {
        print $count;
    }
}
```

Code above print 111
Please tell me, why not work conditional **unless** without declaration variable my $count?

Comment: `use warnings;`

Comment: and you probably want to turn that `unless` into an `if`. Or it'll try to print `undef`.

Comment: Why are you iterating over your array ref and then grepping inside the loop over the complete array ref again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't it work? Well, because of `@{$list}+0`. You are adding a scalar to a list -- you will get a scalar as a result (size of the array, in this example `3`). You are then grepping the scalar instead of the list.

Also, `$count` in your first example is not defined at all.

Using `@{$list}` instead of `@{$list}+0` would work as you expect, i.e.:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $list=[{"name"=>1},{"name"=>1},{"name"=>2}];

foreach my $cat(@{$list}) {
    unless(grep { $_->{name} eq 3 } @$list) {
        print "Hello there.\n";
    }
}
```